# Ensure pickling is complete before ProcessPoolExecutor.submit returns

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

Say I have the following simple class (easily pickled):

```py
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

class A:
    def long_computation(self):
        time.sleep(10)
        return 42
```

I would like to be able to do this:

```py
a = A()

with ProcessPoolExecutor(1) as executor:
    a.future = executor.submit(a.long_computation)
```

On Python 3.6.9, this fails with `TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects`. On 3.8.0, it results in an endless wait for a lock to be acquired.

What does work (on both versions) is this:

```py
a = A()

with ProcessPoolExecutor(1) as executor:
    future = executor.submit(a.long_computation)
    time.sleep(0.001)
    a.future = future
```

It seems to me that `executor.submit` does not block long enough for the pickling of `a` to finish, and runs into issues with pickling the resulting `Future` object.

I'm not too happy about the `time.sleep(0.001)` workaround, as it involves a magic number and I imagine it could easily fail if the pickling ends up taking longer. I don't want to sleep for a safer, longer time as that would be a waste. Ideally I would want `executor.submit` to block until it is safe to store a reference to the `Future` object in `a`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking about it a bit more, I came up with the following:

```py
import pickle

a = A()

with ProcessPoolExecutor(1) as executor:
    a.future = executor.submit(pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(a)).long_computation)
```

It involves a duplication of effort as the `a` is pickled twice, but works fine and ensures that the `Future` object does not get pickled in any case, as desired.

Then I realised that the reason this works is that it creates a copy of `a`. So the pickling and unpickling can be avoided by simply (shallow) copying the object before submitting the method, which ensures that no reference to the `Future` object exists on the copy:

```py
from copy import copy

a = A()

with ProcessPoolExecutor(1) as executor:
    a.future = executor.submit(copy(a).long_computation)
```

This is faster and much less awkward than the above cycle of pickles, but I'm still interested in the best practice here so I'll wait a bit before accepting this answer.